# How to get used elements from space complexity optimized 0-1 knapsack

Tags: c, knapsack-problem

I have implemented 0-1 knapsack. "DP" is the 1D table that holds maximum profits. "capacity" is the maximum capacity, "n" is the number of elements. At the end it holds the last row of 2D classic approach in "DP". But i can't figure out how to get which elements are used with just looking at the 1D array.

```
DP = (int*)calloc(capacity + 1, sizeof(int));
used = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = capacity; j > 0; j--) {
            if (weight[i] <= j && DP[j] < DP[j - weight[i]] + profit[i]) {
                DP[j] = DP[j - weight[i]] + profit[i];
                used[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

// for example
// int profit[] = { 7, 16, 13, 8, 1, 11, 14, 11, 12, 7, 6, 10, 1, 1, 11, 12}
// int weight[] = { 6, 2, 7, 2, 1, 2, 5, 4, 12, 16, 1, 4, 10, 12, 12, 2}
// results DP = {0, 6, 16, 22, 28, 34, 39, 45, 47}

// total profit of used elements: 72 <- it should be 47
// total weight of used elements: 20 <- it should be lesser than 8(the capacity)
```

Comment: for given `j` look for `i` that satisfies `DP[j] == DP[j - weight[i]] + profit[i]`

Comment: I edited the code, but it holds much item than necessary @tstanisl